# Adding contacts and dialing out with Empathy

Tags: empathy, voip

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on a Thinkpad X1 Tablet.  I pay for a VOIP phone and usually use it via a Grandstream HT502 ATA.  But sometimes I would like to use my computer to make the VOIP call.  I installed Empathy and I have set up my SIP account in Empathy.  And when a call came in I was able to answer it but I cannot figure out how to dial out nor how to add a contact.  If I have not set the SIP account to be active the "Contact List" window says "You need to enable one of your accounts to see contacts here" and offers me an `Account settings` button.  Clicking on that button opens the "Messaging and VoIP Accounts" and I can enable my Sip account. Then the "Contact List" says that I am "Offline" and "Change your online presence to see contacts here"  It offers me a `Go Online` button which does not do anything.  In the drop down menu with my status I can change "Offline" to "Available" but as far as I can tell it has no effect.

Empathy's help suggests that to add a contact I choose "Chat -> Add Contact" but I do not see "Chat" anywhere and do not know how to find it.  For initiating an audio conversation, Empathy's help suggests I right-click on the contact I want to call.  But I am unable to add any contacts so this is not possible.

How can I initiate a VoIP phone call?  Is there a way to see a dial-pad?

How can I add a contact?

Once I get Empathy working, I would like to conduct some phone interviews; is it possible to record calls with Empathy?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I have updated to 21.10 and I am having the same problem